# Skip Header row when loading data from csv using Ingest Utility in db2

Tags: db2, data-ingestion, ingest

I am trying to load data into a db2 target table from a csv file using the ingest utility.
I see the header row getting rejected with an error message.
Is there any option (similar to skipcount in import utility) to skip the header row so to avoid getting the rejected message ?

Comment: Is INGEST stopping or is it a warning?

Comment: ingest is not stopping but it shows a warning message everytime saying row rejected.
Is there a way to skip the header row so to avoid this warning message every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a named pipe with [INGEST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest).

Something like this:

```
mkfifo mypipe
tail -n +2 data.csv > mypipe
```

Then read from **mypipe**.

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik it was really useful and  When i run the ingest with the delete statement it gives the number of rows inserted as 0 and doesn't show the number of rows deleted. Is there any option to show the number of rows deleted ?

Comment: Open a new question, I don't know. Thanks for the feedback